# How to bring up inadequate compensation as a reason to jump ship?

Tags: interviewing, salary

It seems like the raise that I will get at my present employer wouldn't be that significant this year & I found that I could get much better pay by jumping ship.

At this point, I have almost 4 years worth of experience (if I count my internships as dev well) and I have been at my present company for 1 year now.

I like working at my present company but my base salary at this point has been same for almost 3 years & I would like it to go up. I am getting same salary here plus a $5k yearly bonus.

Is it okay to bring this up when the interviewer asks why I am looking for a new job?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Citing pay as a reason to move on from a company](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1775/citing-pay-as-a-reason-to-move-on-from-a-company)

Answer (score 12):

> Is it okay to bring this up when the interviewer asks why I am looking
>   for a new job?

### Absolutely.

In the software development industry, some employers just don't keep up from a pay perspective.  What I *would caution you on* is to not make it **the only reason**.  If cash is the **only** reason you may come across as only concerned about money. (we all work for money, but employers want to hear that you interested in more than that)

When they ask, you can say something like "*Lack of growth opportunities, or I would like an opportunity where the commute is better, etc.*"

Lack of growth opportunities is typically understood as your current company not having promotion opportunities or providing the ability to get a decent pay raise.

Comment: Sorry you beat me to it :D

Comment: Absolutely, one more reason I have is that I want to move closer to the Downtown Toronto. My present company's office is way far from there (which is almost an hour worth of drive).

Comment: @fakejsninja If you do this, make sure to imply you have other opportunities lined up willing to meet your salary expectations, or prepare to be lowballed.

Answer (score 7):

> Is it okay to bring this up when the interviewer asks why I am looking for a new job?

There's nothing wrong in telling an interviewer, if they ask why you're looking to work with them, that their higher salary was attractive to you but whatever you do don't let that appear to be the only reason!

Comment: Absolutely, one more reason I have is that I want to move closer to the Downtown Toronto. My present company's office is way far from there (which is almost an hour worth of drive).

Comment: Awesome :) good luck @fakejsninja